# How to add multiple headings in SimpleAdapter List

Tags: java, android

I am using `SAXparser` to fetch data from various feed and then adding it in a single List using `SimpleListAdapter`,

I am using the following code to add the RSS Feed into my `SimpleListAdapter` and updating it for every new Feed,

```
            SimpleAdapter sAdapter = null;

            String[] keys = { Feeds.TITLES, Feeds.KEY };
            int[] ids = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

            if (sAdapter == null) {
                sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(Main.this, fetchedData,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, keys, ids);
                setListAdapter(sAdapter);
            }
```

This updates the Adapter for the next feed instead of re-creating the adapter.

```
            else 
                sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The problem with the code is, there is no way to know when the new feed is started since all the data is in one list and I want to add heading before first feed and when each feed is ended.

Is there anyway that I can add headings after every RSS Feed in the list ?

This is what I am getting rightnow,

Feed Data from Feed 1

Feed Data from Feed 1

Feed Data from Feed 1

Feed Data from Feed 1

Feed Data from Feed 2

Feed Data from Feed 2

Feed Data from Feed 2

Feed Data from Feed 2

Feed Data from Feed 3

Feed Data from Feed 3

Feed Data from Feed 3

Feed Data from Feed 3

Feed Data from Feed 3

This is what I want,

**Heading 1**

Feed Data from Feed 1

Feed Data from Feed 1

Feed Data from Feed 1

Feed Data from Feed 1

**Heading 2**

Feed Data from Feed 2

Feed Data from Feed 2

Feed Data from Feed 2

Feed Data from Feed 2

**Heading 3**

Feed Data from Feed 3

Feed Data from Feed 3

Feed Data from Feed 3

Feed Data from Feed 3

Feed Data from Feed 3

Comment: It's not a heading if it's in the middle of the list, right? I think you'd have to use separate lists.

Comment: this wouldn't be an efficient way i guess ? shouldn't there be a way to add heading(or whatever you want to call it) in the middle of the list ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot ways to do it, listView with headers, I recommend you to check this link

link http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/08/section-header-listview-in-android.html?m=1